# TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: com.netelixir.lxr.google.entities.CampaignStructure

Tags: java, hibernate

When I'am trying to update the table its showing the above exception.
 my model class is

```
@Entity
@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_structure")
@CsvReport(value = ReportDefinitionReportType.CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
public class CampaignStructure extends Report implements Serializable{

  @Column(name = "CAMPAIGN_ID")
  @CsvField(value = "Campaign ID", reportField = "CampaignId")
  private Long campaignId;

  @Column(name = "CAMPAIGN_NAME", length = 255)
  @CsvField(value = "Campaign", reportField = "CampaignName")
  private String campaignName;

  @Column(name = "CAMPAIGN_STATUS", length = 32)
  @CsvField(value = "Campaign state", reportField = "CampaignStatus")
  private String campaignStatus;

  @Column(name = "BUDGET")
  @CsvField(value = "Budget", reportField = "Amount")
  @MoneyField
  private BigDecimal budget;

  @Column(name = "BUDGET_ID")
  @CsvField(value = "Budget ID", reportField = "BudgetId")
  private Long budgetId;

  @Lob
  @Column(name = "LABELS", length = 2048)
  @CsvField(value = "Labels", reportField = "Labels")
  private String labels;
  @Lob
  @Column(name = "LABEL_IDS", length = 2048)
  @CsvField(value = "Label IDs", reportField = "LabelIds")
  private String labelIds;


  @Column(name = "ADVERTISING_CHANNEL_TYPE", length = 32)
  @CsvField(value = "Advertising Channel", reportField = "AdvertisingChannelType")
  protected String advertisingChannelType;

  @Column(name = "ADVERTISING_CHANNEL_SUBTYPE", length = 32)
  @CsvField(value = "Advertising Sub Channel", reportField = "AdvertisingChannelSubType")
  protected String advertisingChannelSubType;


  @Column(name = "TRACKING_URL_TEMPLATE", length=2048)
  @CsvField(value = "Tracking template", reportField = "TrackingUrlTemplate")
  private String trackingUrlTemplate;

  @Column(name = "URL_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS", length=2048)
  @CsvField(value = "Custom parameter", reportField = "UrlCustomParameters")
  private String urlCustomParameters;

  @Column(name = "START_DATE", length=2048)
  @CsvField(value = "Start date", reportField = "StartDate")
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date startDate;

  @Column(name = "END_DATE", length=2048)
  @CsvField(value = "End date", reportField = "EndDate")
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
```

my Dao class[UPDATED one]

```
    public void updateCampaign(Campaign campaigns,GleServices gleServices){
              Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          Transaction tx = null;
          try{
          session = sessionFactory.openSession();
          StringBuilder updateStmt = new StringBuilder();
updateStmt.append(" update CampaignStructure ");
updateStmt.append(" set accountId = :accountId ");
updateStmt.append(" , budget = :budget ");
updateStmt.append(" , campaignName= :campaignName ");
updateStmt.append(", budgetId = :budgetId");
updateStmt.append(", campaignStatus = :campaignStatus");
updateStmt.append(", startDate = :startDate");
updateStmt.append(", endDate = :endDate");
updateStmt.append(", trackingUrlTemplate = :trackingUrlTemplate");
updateStmt.append(", urlCustomParameters = :urlCustomParameters");
updateStmt.append(", labels = :labels");
updateStmt.append(" where campaignId = :campaignId");
Query query = session.createQuery(updateStmt.toString());
query.setParameter("accountId", gleServices.getAccountDetails().getSeAccountId());
query.setParameter("budget", BigDecimal.valueOf((campaigns.getBudget().getAmount().getMicroAmount())));
query.setParameter("campaignId", campaigns.getId());
query.setParameter("campaignName", campaigns.getName());
query.setParameter("budgetId", campaigns.getBudget().getBudgetId());
query.setParameter("campaignStatus", campaigns.getStatus());
query.setParameter("startDate", campaigns.getStartDate());
query.setParameter("endDate", campaigns.getEndDate());
query.setParameter("trackingUrlTemplate", campaigns.getTrackingUrlTemplate());
if(campaigns.getUrlCustomParameters() != null){
                      query.setParameter("urlCustomParameters",getUrlCustomParams(campaigns.getUrlCustomParameters().getParameters()));  
                    }else{
                      query.setParameter("urlCustomParameters",null);    
                    }
 if(campaigns.getLabels()!=null){
//        campaignStructure.setLabels(campaigns.getLabels().toString());
        query.setParameter("labels", campaigns.getLabels().toString());
        }
        else
        query.setParameter("labels", null);
query.executeUpdate();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
             e.printStackTrace(); 
          }finally {
             session.close(); 
          }        

        }
```

in campaigns variable we get all the data, from campaign i need to update all the data to (campaign_structure)table

Comment: You have no field with @Id annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to update an entity without loading it to persistenece context beforehand..

You were quite close, if you just uncomment:

```
CampaignStructure campaignStructure = 
   (CampaignStructure) session.load(CampaignStructure.class, Long.valueOf(campaigns.getId()));
```

Also, you will need to add `@Id` annotation to `campaignId` field in your entity to let the persistence provider know by what field should it query for the entity.

**Update**

If you cannot change the entity signature, then you would have to use the bulk update feature. You would do something like:

```
StringBuilder updateStmt = new StringBuilder();
updateStmt.append("update CampaignStructure ");
updateStmt.append("set accountId = :accountId ");
updateStmt.append(", budget = :budget");
...
updateStmt.append(" where campaignId = :campaignId");
```

then create a query and update the parameters:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(updateStmt.toString());
query.setParameter("accountId", accountId);
query.setParameter("budget", budget);
...
query.setParameter("campaignId", campaignId);
```

finally execute:

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

Bulk updates / deletes are the last resort in general and this would be definately a workaround.. but if you cannot change the entity signature, you are let with this solution if you want to use HQL.

Comment: ThankYou for the quick respose.. I want to know  is there any way to update table without changing any fields of entity class

Comment: when i uncommented the CampaignStructure campaignStructure = 
   (CampaignStructure) session.load(CampaignStructure.class, Long.valueOf(campaigns.getId())); line this exception is occuring org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.netelixir.lxr.google.entities.CampaignStructure#704734966].

Comment: So you cannot add @Id annotation?

Comment: did you use this code Long.valueOf(campaigns.getId()).. to load pass the id to find the entity?

Comment: Yeah i Cannot add @id

Comment: i haved upadted the answer. check it out

Comment: as per ur instruction i have edited the code as StringBuilder updateStmt = new StringBuilder();
updateStmt.append("update CampaignStructure ");
updateStmt.append("set accountId = :accountId");
updateStmt.append("set campaignId = :campaignId");
Query query = session.createQuery(updateStmt.toString());
query.setParameter("accountId", gleServices.getAccountDetails().getSeAccountId());
query.setParameter("campaignId", campaigns.getId());
..Its throwing exception as  ErrorCounter,50: line 1:90: unexpected token: campaignId
line 1:90: unexpected token: campaignId

Comment: 1) Dont forget about the where clause .. 2) Try adding spaces at the end of each append. 3) You only use one SET clause then you split each column with ','.

Comment: Try adding space..updateStmt.append("  set accountId = :accountId  "); so that statements dont get concatenated. 2) SET can be used only once, then you just separate columns by ','.... update A SET col1 = :col1, col2 = :col2, col3 = :col3 where col4 = :col4

Comment: I have added spaces even though its throwing same error. unexpected token: budget

Comment: maybe post an update in your question with your current code.. will be easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137347/discussion-between-eshwar-chettri-and-maciej-kowalski).